# Need help delegating my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have a little jquery plugin for ellipsing text. The problem is that now i need to use this plugin in a dinamically content (using knockout). How could i use this plugin in all elements of the page if they are being loaded dinamically?

My plugin:

```
(function ($){

    $.fn.ellipsiText= function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        length : 30,
        ellipsi : "..."
        }, options );

return this.each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var txt = elem.text();
    if (txt.length>settings.length) {
         elem.text(txt.substr(0,settings.length - settings.ellipsi.length) + settings.ellipsi );
    }
});

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Same function you can convert into knockout custom binding.

ellipsiText Binding:-

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ellipsiText = {
 init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $el = $(element);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($el.val());
    });
 },
 update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().ellipsiTextOptions || {};
    var settings = $.extend({
        length: 30,
        ellipsi: "..."
    }, options);
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var $element = $(element);
    var txt = value();
    if (txt.length > settings.length) {
        $element.text(txt.substr(0, settings.length - settings.ellipsi.length) + settings.ellipsi);
    }else {
        $element.text(txt);
    }
 }
};
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SJCPT/1/)

Comment: There is a way to do that without changing things in knockout? I actually dont know a thing about knockout, but the code in my whole system uses it (i didnt made) and if i just add this in a script tag, the console says "ko" is not defined, so im doing something wrong.

Comment: I have updated the solution. before adding this under script tag you have to add reference of knockoutjs library.